# Charles Proxy SSL: "SSL Proxying not enabled for this host"

Tags: charles-proxy

Why am I not able to see responses in Charles Proxy when debugging an app?

It is very strange, all certificates have been installed on my laptop and trusted, same for my devices, and I am still getting `SSL Proxying not enabled for this host`, even though I have the enable SSL box ticked.

I have never run into this issue before. What can I do?

Answer (score 70):

Charles Proxy does not proxy any domain unless specified in the Proxy Settings. It's on the [Charles Proxy Documentation](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/):

> You must specifically identify the host names you want to enable SSL Proxying on. The list is in the Proxy Settings, SSL tab. You can also right-click on a host name in the structure view and turn on or off SSL Proxying.

If you want all HTTPS traffic to be captured by Charles, then you can add *:* on that list:
[image]

Comment: You can add `*:*` to that list by entering * for the host and * for the port. (Thanks to @Faizyy for the correction)

Comment: In my case, on OSX 11.6 specifying host did not work (it should have), right click on host name in structure view did not work (it should have), only when I set "*:*" did it work. Thanks!

Comment: this is the way. on iOS 16 you must also trust the certificate (settings - general - about - certificate trust settings)

Answer (score 47):

If you're looking to only monitor few domains related to your app. A Simple solution would be, just right click on the domain name that you're trying to monitor and in the context menu shown, click `Enable SSL Proxying`, charles will take care of filling the url and port itself.

[image]

Comment: The simplest solution.  Doesn't require any manual fiddling inside of Charles.

Comment: it is already enabled for me. Says "Disable SSL Proxying" instead, but all requests still appear as "unknown" and says SSL is not enabled from them

Comment: You need to add charles CA certificate on your mobile device and add res/xml/network_security_config.xml file for android apk, for iOS 16 you need to trust certificate in settings general/about/certificate/trust settings.

Comment: @george-shalvashvili i am experiencing the same thing on Charles version 4.6.5 for Windows