# The characters are unreadable in the http requests and responses captured by Charles

Tags: charles-proxy

I use Charles on Windows 10 to capture network requests and responses.

But the characters in the requests and responses are unreadable.
[image]

How can I make these characters readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to read SSL based HTTP requests (this is: https requests).

Roughly what you need to do is enable SSL in Charles. Everything you need you will find it in the `SSL Proxy Settings`, under the `Proxy`menu:

1. [Install the Charles certificate](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) on your browser
2. [Add the domains you want to inspect to the proper SSL  Proxy Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117151/charles-proxy-ssl-ssl-proxying-not-enabled-for-this-host/49129286#49129286).

This should give you the same screen with all the content you expected to see without any kind of encryption.